# Results DataSet from DynamoDB Query using GSI is not returning correct results

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo DB table where I am currently storing all the events that are happening in my system with respect to every product. There is a primary key with a Hash combination of productid,eventtype and eventcategory and Sort Key as Creation Time on the main table. The table was created and data was added into it.

Later I added a new GSI on the table with the attributes being Secondary Hash (which is just the combination of eventcategory and eventtype (excluding productid) and CreationTime as Sort Key. This was added so that I can query for multiple products at once.

The GSI seems to work fine, However only later I realized the data being returned is incorrect

Here is the scenario. (I am running all these queries against the newly created index)
I was querying for products with in the last 30 days and the Query returns 312 records, However, when I run the same query for last 90 days, it returns me only 128 records (which is wrong, should be atleast equal or greater than last 30 days records)

I have the pagination logic already embedded in my code, so that the lastEvaluatedKey is verified every-time, to loop and fetch the next set of records and after the loop, all the results are combined.

Not sure if I am missing something.

ANy suggestions would be appreciated.

```
var limitPtr *int64
    if limit > 0 {
        limit64 := int64(limit)
        limitPtr = &limit64
    }
input := dynamodb.QueryInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#sch": aws.String("SecondaryHash"),
            "#pkr": aws.String("CreationTime"),
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":sch": {
                S: aws.String(eventHash),
            },
            ":pkr1": {
                N: aws.String(strconv.FormatInt(startTime, 10)),
            },
            ":pkr2": {
                N: aws.String(strconv.FormatInt(endTime, 10)),
            },
        },
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#sch = :sch AND #pkr BETWEEN :pkr1 AND :pkr2"),
        ScanIndexForward:       &scanForward,
        Limit:                  limitPtr,
        TableName:              aws.String(ddbTableName),
        IndexName:              aws.String(ddbIndexName),
    }
```

Comment: Verify your result by querying in the DynamoDB console.

Answer (score 2):

You reached the maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items). The limit is 1 MB.

The response will contain a **LastEvaluatedKey** parameter, it is the last item's id. You have to perform a new query with an extra **ExclusiveStartKey** parameter. (ExclusiveStartKey should be equal with LastEvaluatedKey's value.)

When the **LastEvaluatedKey** is empty you reached the end of the table.